# Does anyone know how I could fix this code to make my webpage open in an about:blank page?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to make one of my website pages open in an about:blank URL before/when it's opened. But, my code isn't working for some reason even when I have it embeded in my index.html, here is my code so far:

````
function onLoad(){
  let inFrame

try {
    inFrame = window !== top
} catch (e) {
    inFrame = true
}

if (!inFrame && !navigator.userAgent.includes("Firefox")) {
const popup = open("about:blank", "_blank")
if (!popup || popup.closed) {
  alert("Popups are disabled!")
} else {
  const doc = popup.document
  const iframe = doc.createElement("iframe")
  const style = iframe.style
  const img = doc.createElement("link")

  img.rel = "icon"
  img.href = "https://google.com/favicon.ico"
  doc.title = "Google"

  iframe.src = location.href
  style.position = "fixed"
  style.top = style.bottom = style.left = style.right = 0
  style.border = style.outline = "none"
  style.width = style.height = "100%"

  doc.body.appendChild(iframe)
  location.replace("https://google.com")
    }
}

}```
 Can anyone help me?
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you whole index.html but I tried your code by putting it on index.html script tag and call onload() with having about.html page in my directory and it worked the only problem I got is popup was blocked by browser please check if that's the case enable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in `onLoad` function , can you please explain the try block. if the try block is equating `window` object to a variable or a string, then that is the error. please re-check it. if possible provide some more details in code.